# How to find out if window with certain name was closed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Generally my question is how to find in array of windows which one was closed?

I open lots of popUp windows and make them stay on top, but I have a problem with finding if window was closed already. So I do something like:

```
var exNames = []; var wins = []; var w=0; var h=0; var maxHeight = 0;

openWin = function(name, width, height){
 var myJoin = "|" + exNames.join("|") + "|";
if(myJoin.indexOf('|'+name+'|') == -1){
 
    if(height > maxHeight){ maxHeight = height + 5;}
    if(screen.width - w - width < 0){w=0;  h=h+maxHeight; top=h+1; maxHeight=0; if(screen.height - h - height < 0){h=0;} } 
    
    left=w+1;
    tops=h+1;
    w=w+width+7;
    
    var file='./'+name+'.flv?action=read';
    var settings='width='+width+', height='+height+', left='+left+', top='+tops+', screenX='+left+', screenY='+tops;
     wins.push(window.open(file, name, settings));
         exNames.push(name);


}          for (var i = 0; i < wins.length; ++i)
            wins[i].focus();
}
```

And I need to know when someone sends me name of a window which was already opened and closed to restore that window. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using the `window.closed` property http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/win_closed.html